# How to customise unique = true in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

ok basically, users on my website can create blogposts. But I do not want to use unique = True because that'll mean that user1 cannot create a post that has the same title as user2.

I want to make it such that user1 can create a post that has the same title as user2 BUT user1 CANNOT create another post with the same name as any existing post that USER1 has previously created.

Meaning user 1 can have a blogpost title "hello" and user 2 can also have a blogpost "hello"
but user 1 cannot have 2 blogpost with the same title 'hello'

Ok i think this is clear enough^....if I use unique = true, this would be too much, so how can I customise that such that it only applies to the user's post? Thanks!

models.py

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
 title                  = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
 author                     = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 slug                   = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)

class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
 email                  = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
 username               = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
```

forms.py

```
class CreateBlogPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ['chief_title']
```

html

```
   <form class="create-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="id_title">Title</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title" id="id_title" placeholder="Title" required autofocus>
   </div>
   <button class="submit-button btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>

  </form>

  {% if form.errors %}
  {% for field in form %}
      {% for error in field.errors %}
          <div class="alert alert-danger">
              <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
          </div>
      {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

views.py

```
def create_blog_view(request):
    context = {}
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateBlogPostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)    
        if form.is_valid():
            obj.save()
            return redirect('HomeFeed:main')
        else:
            context['form'] = form
    return render(request, "HomeFeed/create_blog.html", context)
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use a [unique constraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint), this allows 2 fields to interact and be unique so you could have a post name that can only be used once per user

Comment: Hey man, how would this look like in code? Is it just `UniqueConstraint(fields=['chief_title', 'author'], name='unique_blogpost')` ? I will include this in my models.py after all the fields? Do I need to include anything in my views.py and html etc? @Sirwill98

Comment: Also, i assume that by doing that, i won't need unique=True in my title field anymore right

Comment: they are added in the `meta:` class in the model, [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.constraints) shows an example

Comment: and yes you could remove the unique attribute

Comment: sure, after this is done^, would I need to add anything in my views.py and html to show the error if it the unique constraint happens to be breached? or is what i already have in html sufficient?

Comment: im not super familiar with this particular condition but it should throw an error on a breach of it and it would be caught as a form error

Comment: sure, let me test the code and get back to you on sunday. meanwhile will upvote first :)